# Why are the splitting fields of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ always Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Why are the splitting fields of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ always Galois? Is that a theorem? Some knowledge too common to write down? I'm just curious because I don't think I've come across that statement in my textbook.

Comment: Often it's *by definition*. There are many definitions of "Galois." Which one(s) are you familiar with? I'm guessing "normal + separable." Understanding the equivalence of definitions of Galois is (or should be) a rite of passage in Galois theory. The most efficient way to prove it is to first equip the primitive element theorem $-$ do you happen to have that handy?

Comment: "Let $K$ be a field, $f(x)\in K[x]$ & $F$ be splitting field for $f(x)$ over $K$. Then $Gal(F/K)$ is the \textbf{Galois Group} of $f(x)$ over $K$, or the \textbf{Galois group of the equation} $f(x)=0$ over $K$." I'm still working through what it means exactly.

Comment: That's the definition of the Galois *group* of a splitting field or equivalently of a polynomial. I'm asking you what the definition (your text has) of a *field extension being Galois* - you have already insinuated that your text does not use the definition "is a splitting field." Surely you wouldn't ask why splitting fields are "Galois" if you don't have a definition for the adjective "Galois"?

Comment: @anon I can't find any.

Comment: Okay. Then what do *you* mean by "Galois" when you ask the question "why are splitting fields Galois"? Should we just go with "normal + separable" as I suggested? I don't understand why you would ask without knowing what the word Galois means. It might also help to actually state what book you use.

Comment: Professor handouts from class. I was trying to learn more about Galois theory  and I found a comment mentioning it on StackExchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471607/determining-a-splitting-field

Comment: @anon The recommended (not required) text is Abstract Algebra by John Beachy.

Comment: It should be clear to you that for your question to make sense (to you!) you need to have a definition of what a Galois extensión is!